# Writing all output to a file

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following code to get a list of machines with IP addresses.  It prints out the hostname and IP address.  If the host is offline, it says "$computername is offline."  Here is the code:

```
$csv = Get-Content TEST_MACHINES.csv

foreach ($computer in $csv)
{
    try
    {
         Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop | Select Address, IPV4Address 
    }
    catch
    {
         "$computer is offline" 
    }
 }
```

It works great and outputs the data like so:

Address                            IPV4Address

-------                            -----------

TESTMACHINE                        192.168.1.1

TESTMACHINE2                       192.168.1.2

TESTMACHINE3  is offline.

However no amount of trickery is allowing me to write all of this to a file, even though it's displaying like that in the console.  It writes to a blank file or only writes the exception.

How can I capture this output exactly as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom powershell object using the same field names as the test-connection fields you are selecting and then export both success and failure to CSV. See below for an example:

```
$csv = Get-Content TEST_MACHINES.csv

foreach ($computer in $csv)
{
    try
    {
        Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop | Select Address, IPV4Address | Export-Csv -Path .\ConnectionTest.csv -Append
    }
    catch
    {
        $Output = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Address = $computer
            IPV4Address = "Offline"
        }

        $Output | Export-Csv -Path .\ConnectionTest.csv -Append
    }
 }
```

Comment: That only writes the first section of the script.  It's really appearing perfectly in the console, but if I run the script like "./script.ps1 > results.txt" the results.txt file is blank.  How can I just get it to output EVERYTHING to the results file?

Comment: Sorry, this response is a little late. The code above, as written, will not produce any output to standard out, so redirecting it by using > results.txt would indeed result in an empty results.txt file.

All standard output resulting from the code above was piped to Export-Csv, which would place all output in the file specified in the Export-Csv -Path argument. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my style of writing scripts I'd use simple if..then..else loop. It seems most logical to me. You did try the "Out-File" switch after pipe, didn't you?... I have just run the below on localhost and some random name, and that worked just fine...

```
$csv = Get-Content TEST_MACHINES.csv

foreach ($computer in $csv)
{
    if (Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
    Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop | Select Address, IPV4Address | Out-file -append "SomeFile.txt"
    }
    else
    {
    "$computer is offline" | Out-File -Append "SomeFile.txt"
    }
 }
```

Comment: For me this generates an empty "somefile.txt"

Comment: When I post a command I try it with some input... I put "localhost" and "www.google.com" inside a csv file and it gave me output just fine for PS4.0 Can you share lets say first 3 lines of CSV file? Or try with a normal file which contains exactly 1 entry per line?
EDIT: Strange you received the blank file from Branden script as well...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$csv = Get-Content TEST_MACHINES.csv
'' > foo.log
foreach ($computer in $csv)
{
    try
    {
         Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop | Select Address, IPV4Address >> foo.log
    }
    catch
    {
         "$computer is offline" >> foo.log
    }
 }
```